# Why its failed on linux server?

Tags: linux

[image]

I tried to mark disk and got Fail!!!

[root@oradbserver3 Server]# /etc/init.d/oracleasm createdisk DISK1 /dev/sda2

Marking disk "DISK1" as an ASM disk:                       [FAILED]

Answer (score 2):

You just need to do:

```
/etc/init.d/oracleasm start
```

.... to start off with.

Look at your screenshot - you completely ignored the fact that the `oracleasm` command gave you the command-line usage back, rather than actually doing anything.

Comment: Its not working for me... thank you anyway...

Comment: @Genghis help us to help you - what was the error?

Comment: I found I did configuration in a wrong way... thank you)

Answer (score -1):

Try following

load the kernel module

```
modprobe oracleasm
```

other option is using RAW devices for ASM.

```
raw /dev/raw/rawX /dev/sdX1 
chown oracle:dba /dev/raw/raw1
chmod 660 /dev/raw/rawX
```

This is a  good tutorial on youtube (due to selinux enabled)

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JRrNuudTBR4